# saving hibernate objects using stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures, orm

I have a scenario where-in i need to persist an entity and its dependent objects into database. I have run into a position where-in i have to insert about 50000 such objects one after the other from a web application. Now doing this in a loop would take about 3 hours to process.

I want to change the approach to pass the hibernate entities to a stored procedure and execute them on the database side since this would take considerably lesser time in execution.

I want to know if this can be done and if yes, how can this be accomplished. The following example can be taken as reference.

Parent A, Parent B - Both may or may not have dependency.
Parent C - Independent parent.
Parent B has 3 children - Child A, Child B, Child C.
Child B has also reference to parent C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to change the approach to pass the hibernate entities to a
>   stored procedure

That sounds like a very bad idea. Like putting bacon in my christmas pudding, both very good but should not be mixed.

Have you seen [hibernate batch](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) its for exactly this problem.